# K-Means of Tensorflow - Graph disconnected error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, k-means

I am trying to write a function that runs `KMeans` on a dataset and outputs the cluster centroids. My aim is to use this in a custom `keras` layer, so I am using `TensorFlow`'s implementation of KMeans that takes a tensor as the input dataset.

My problem however is that I can't make it work even as a standalone function. The problem comes from the fact that `KMeans` accepts a **generator function** that provides mini-batches instead of a plain tensor, but when I am using closure to do that, I get a `graph disconnected` error:

```py
import tensorflow as tf                                           # version: 2.4.1
from tensorflow.compat.v1.estimator.experimental import KMeans

@tf.function
def KMeansCentroids(inputs, num_clusters, steps, use_mini_batch=False):
    # `inputs` is a 2D tensor

    def input_fn():
        # Each one of the lines below results in the same "Graph Disconnected" error. Tuples don't really needed but just to be consistent with the documentation
        return (inputs, None)
        return (tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(inputs), None)
        return (tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs), None)
            
    kmeans = KMeans(
            num_clusters=num_clusters,
            use_mini_batch=use_mini_batch)
        
    kmeans.train(input_fn, steps=steps)     # This is where the error happens
    return kmeans.cluster_centers()

>>> x = tf.random.uniform((100, 2))
>>> c = KMeansCentroids(x, 5, 10)
```

The exact error is:

> ValueError:
> `Tensor("strided_slice:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)`
> must be from the same graph as
> `Tensor("Equal:0", shape=(), dtype=bool)`
> (graphs are `FuncGraph(name=KMeansCentroids, id=..)` and `<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at ...>`).

- If I were to use a `numpy` dataset and convert to tensor inside the function, the code would work just fine.
- Also, making `input_fn()` return directly `tf.random.uniform((100, 2))` (ignoring the inputs argument), would again work. That's why I am guessing that tensorflow doesn't support closures since it needs to build the computation graph at the beginning.
  But I don't see how to work around that.
  Could it be a version error due to KMeans being a `compat.v1.experimental` module?

---

Note that the [documentation of KMeans](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/experimental/KMeans) states for the `input_fn()`:

> The function should construct and return one of the following:
>
> - A tf.data.Dataset object: Outputs of Dataset object must be a tuple (features, labels) with same constraints as below.
> - A tuple (features, labels): Where features is a tf.Tensor or a dictionary of string feature name to Tensor and labels is a Tensor or a dictionary of string label name to Tensor. Both features and labels are consumed by model_fn. They should satisfy the expectation of model_fn from inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is more about invoking tensor outside the created graph. Basically, when you called the `.train` function, a new graph will be created and that is with the graph defined in that `input_fn` and the graph defined in the `model_fn`.

```
kmeans.train(input_fn, steps=steps)
```

And, after that all the tensors those coming outside these functions will be treated as outsiders and won't part of this new graph. That's why you're getting a `graph disconnected` error for trying to use outsider tensor. To resolve this, you need to create the necessary tensors within these graphs.

```
import tensorflow as tf                                        
from tensorflow.compat.v1.estimator.experimental import KMeans

@tf.function
def KMeansCentroids(num_clusters, steps, use_mini_batch=False):
    def input_fn(batch_size):
        pinputs = tf.random.uniform((100, 2))
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((pinputs))
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat()
        return dataset.batch(batch_size)

    kmeans = KMeans(
            num_clusters=num_clusters,
            use_mini_batch=use_mini_batch)
    
    kmeans.train(input_fn = lambda: input_fn(5), 
                 steps=steps)     
    
    return kmeans.cluster_centers()

c = KMeansCentroids(5, 10)
```

Here is some more info for reading, [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4026#issuecomment-242822636). FYI, I tested your code with a few versions of `tf > 2`, and I don't think it's related to version error or something.

---

Re-mentioning here for future readers. An alternative of using `KMeans` within `Keras` layers:

- [tf_kmeans.py](https://github.com/swghosh/UG-Courses/blob/58a282a55e58f35cb27b48cb6366dddf70a07d83/CSE2705/tf_kmeans.py#L6)
- [ClusteringLayer](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-do-unsupervised-clustering-with-keras/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you are saying is correct, and I mentioned that generating the data inside the `input_fn()` would work. But unfortunately, I want to incorporate the `KMeansCentroids()` function inside a custom `keras.Layer`. So I cannot know the input beforehand. They  become available in the as a parameter in `Layer.call()`. So I would need to combine the graphs in some way.

Comment: Have you tried lazy initialization within `Layer. build()`?

Comment: Yes. The problem is always the same due to the need of capturing a "global" variable in `input_fn()` It seems there should be a standard way to "append" tensors/operations/functions to an existing graph

Comment: I see. Then can you add some minimum code that you've tried with a custom layer? You don't need to write any 'what is that about' stuff, others may find info from here.

Comment: Have you checked these, [tf_kmeans.py](https://github.com/swghosh/UG-Courses/blob/master/CSE2705/tf_kmeans.py), [ClusteringLayer](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-do-unsupervised-clustering-with-keras/) - any good?

Comment: Since I couldn't find a workaround to my current solution, I suppose implementing k-means myself within the layer is an acceptable way to go forward.

Comment: You did a very good question with a decent investigation. Your main aim was to use KMeans inside a `keras` layer. But your question highlights more the fact of invoking tensor that was coming outside the created graph. In the end, you didn't also mention the need to use KMeans inside a layer. So, I think if you finished your query asking to find a workaround for using KMeans inside a layer, that would be more precise. But anyway, good question, bookmarked.

Comment: Well I knew from the beginning that a workaround was possible. My question was framed in a way to learn about this specific behavior of tensorflow though. Since it's been a week and despite the bounty, I wasn't able to get a direct answer, I chose to go with it. It's only fair to give you the bounty for assisting me, but I am not accepting your answer to potentially motivate others to help me understand how to solve this specific error.